# jquery script works in Chrome but not in Firefox and ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, blogger

I'm using a social script locker to lock the download links in my blogspot. The script runs perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox or ie. I have many scripts in my blog, I noticed if I change the order of these scripts, some of them stop working again in firefox and ie but not in Chrome. I also noticed that the demo page where I found the script at the first place works fine on either browsers.

This is the code:

```
<link href='https://sites.google.com/site/menightfury/home/social-locker/public/sociallocker_v1.6.0.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://sites.google.com/site/menightfury/home/social-locker/public/sociallockermin_v1.6.0.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#default-usage .to-lock').sociallocker({

    buttons: {order:["facebook-like","twitter-tweet","google-plus"]},

    twitter: {url:"http://twitter.com/menightfury"},
    facebook: {url:"https://www.facebook.com/bloganalyzer.nightfury"},
    google: {url:"https://plus.google.com/+BloganalyzerBlogspot"},

    text: {
    header: "Like us To Unlock This Content",
    message: "This content is locked. Like us on Twitter, Facebook or Google plus to unlock it."
    },

    locker: {close: false, timer: 0,},
    theme: "secrets"
    });
});
  //]]>
</script>
```

And inside the post:

```
<div id="default-usage">
 <div class="to-lock" style="display:none;">

  -- Hidden Content Starts --

 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the demo page: http://bloganalyzer-demo.blogspot.in/2014/04/social-locker.html

I really cannot understand where the problem is. So anyone have any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: If you use the inspect element tool in chrome, it is showing that you have 16 JavaScript errors, and 4 cautionary errors, be sure you have the proper JavaScript libraries loaded, and they are organized in the right order

Comment: `locker: {close: false, timer: 0,},` you have an extra comma after the `0` here. I know IE is extra sensitive to syntax errors such as this; I suggest linting your JS.

Comment: Thanks man. I removed it but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Use the Console tab of Developer tools or FX Inspect Element to list content/scripts blocked by tracking protection.

SEC7114: A download in this page was blocked by Tracking Protection.
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

SEC7114: A download in this page was blocked by Tracking Protection.
http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js

SEC7114: A download in this page was blocked by Tracking Protection.
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js

additionally MSIE shows several security errors.

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://www.blogger.com/navbar.g?targetBlogID=8208953061612638933&blogName=Bloganalyzer+Demo&publishMode=PUBLISH_MODE_BLOGSPOT&navbarType=LIGHT&layoutType=LAYOUTS&searchRoot=http://bloganalyzer-demo.blogspot.com/search&blogLocale=en&v=2&homepageUrl=http://bloganalyzer-demo.blogspot.com/&targetPostID=2582974382219473010&blogPostOrPageUrl=http://bloganalyzer-demo.blogspot.com/2014/04/social-locker.html&blogFollowUrl=https://plus.google.com/104144743008290630026&vt=1061116836912067887&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.EOlYdPwYAoY.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNjTAaZGFn8asaWKqP3Y1ZksbJPDA
File: social-locker.html

you can avoid those by using a protocol-less src

<script src="//googleanalytics.js"></script>

.... I think google already offer analytics for bloggers using BlogSpot.....

the concept of a blog analyzer for blogger.com is a duplication of google's visitor metrics.